# Convert Python request to Javascript XMLHttpRequest with Images

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

I've got a Python code that's POSTing well into an API endpoint:

```
msg = {}
msg['id'] = 1

d = {}
d['message'] = msg

f = {}
f['image'] = "<binary image data>"
f['thumb'] = "<binary image data>"

r = requests.post('/api/url', data=d, files=f)
```

However, when I convert it to Javascript `XMLHttpRequest` it doesn't work well.

Here's my code:

```
var msg = {
   "id": 1
};

var d = {
   "message": msg
}

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("message", JSON.stringify(d));
formData.append("image", "<binary image data>");
formData.append("thumb", "<binary image data>");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/api/url", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

**Output**

XHR is successful, status code is 200 but `id` is wrong and `image` is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: u converted data in different manner, in python f is structure and in js it's not.

Comment: @nullqube, so what are you proposing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @nullqube, thanks for sharing. That's what I'm doing. basically what I want to know is in Python it has the keys: `data` and `files`. So how is that going to play part in Javascript?

Comment: how ur server-side handle that?

Comment: @nullqube, if I know I wouldn't ask the question anymore. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by converting the binary data to `Uint8Array` and then using a `Blob`

```
var msg = {
   "id": 1
};

var formData = new FormData();
var imgUint8Array = new Uint8Array("<binary image data>");
var thumbUint8Array = new Uint8Array("<binary image data>");

formData.append("message", JSON.stringify(msg));
formData.append("image", new Blob([ imgUint8Array ], {type: "image/jpg"}));
formData.append("thumb", new Blob([ thumbUint8Array ], {type: "image/jpg"}));

// ... XHR POST functions
```